# php mysql gallery array sorting

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, web

I Have been trying to sort my images from my database in as a product grid list shown here:

https://www.woothemes.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Mystile-WooCommerce-Homepage-Grid.png...

I don't know what to change in my code I'm stuck. I need help please, Im trying to create an online store.

heres my code:

```
<?php 

// Script Error Reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>
<?php 
// Run a select query to get my letest 6 items
// Connect to the MySQL database  
include "storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
$dynamicList = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 4");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
        $id = $row["id"];
       $product_name = $row["product_name"];
       $price = $row["price"];
       $row = 3;
       $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
       $dynamicList .= '<table width="100" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
        <tr>
          <td width="100%" valign="top"><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><img style="border:#666 1px solid;" src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" width=200" height="150" border="1" /></a></td>
          <td width="100%" valign="top">' . $product_name . '<br />
            $' . $price . '<br />
            <a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '">View Product</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>';
    }
} else {
  $dynamicList = "We have no products listed in our store yet";
}
mysql_close();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Store Home Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<div align="center" id="mainWrapper">
  <?php include_once("template_header.php");?>
  <div id="pageContent">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
  <tr>
    <td width="32%" valign="top"><h3>&nbsp;</h3></td>
    <td width="35%" valign="top"><h3>Latest Designer Fashions</h3>
      <p><?php echo $dynamicList; ?><br />
        </p>

      <p><br />
      </p></td>
    <td width="33%" valign="top"><h3>Handy Tips</h3>
      <p>If you operate any store online you should read the documentation provided to you by the online payment gateway you choose for handling the checkout process. You can get much more insight than I can offer on the various details of a gateway, from the gateway providers themselves. They are there to help you with whatever you need since they get a cut of your online business dealings.</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>

  </div>
  <?php include_once("template_footer.php");?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your linked image has 8 images, but your query has `LIMIT 4`?

Answer (score 0):

remove `$row = 3` from your code to use `$row["date_added"]` and you creating table for each product record .

```
$dynamicList='We have no products listed in our store yet';
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 4");

$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
    if ($productCount > 0) {
        $dynamicList='<table width="100" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">';

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $id = $row["id"];
            $product_name = $row["product_name"];
            $price = $row["price"];
            $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
            $dynamicList.= 'tr><td width="100%" valign="top"><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '">'
                        .'<img style="border:#666 1px solid;" src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" width=200" height="150" border="1" />
                        </a></td><td width="100%" valign="top">' . $product_name . '<br />
                         $' . $price . '<br /><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '">View Product</a></td>
                        </tr>';
        }

        $dynamicList.='</table>';
    } 

    echo $dynamicList;
```

Comment: I deleted $row = 3 but it still grabs images in descending order id like it to look like this https://www.woothemes.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Mystile-WooCommerce-Homepage-Grid.png...

Comment: instead it looks like this https://www.flickr.com/photos/31899902@N05/shares/2H938e

Comment: have you removed table element while cascading sting in foreach loop

Comment: no I havent. my code looks the same. my table is in my php code under php:   $dynamicList .= '<table width="100" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
        <tr>
          <td width="100%" valign="top"><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><img style="border:#666 1px solid;" src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" width=200" height="150" border="1" /></a></td>
          <td width="100%" valign="top">' . $product_name . '<br />
            $' . $price . '<br />
            <a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '">View Product</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>';

Comment: Is that where I have to delete my table is under $dynamiclist .= ? Thank you for your help again also

Comment: is there anyway you can fix my code and show me it done with 3 rows and columns. Its easier for me to see it done